# Need assistance with ForEach loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a string array by combining two arrays using ForEach.

```
$environment = "QA","QA2","Dev","Prod"
$DB =  "OLTP","OLTP5","DW1","DW2"
```

Desired output would look like:

```
QA-OLTP
QA-OLTP5
QA-DW1
QA-DW2
QA2-OLTP
QA2-OLTP5
QA2-DW1
QA2-DW2
DEV-OLTP
DEV-OLTP5
DEV-DW1
DEV-DW2
PROD-OLTP
PROD-OLTP5
PROD-DW1
PROD-DW2
```

Any guidance would be very much appreciated. Thank in advance!

Comment: please format your question.

Comment: Please have a look into how the foreach loop actually works. You can test it out with the following command `foreach($val in $environment){write-output $val}`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want:

```
$environment | foreach{foreach ($d in $db){"$_-$d"}}
```

result:

```
QA-OLTP
QA-OLTP5
QA-DW1
QA-DW2
QA2-OLTP
QA2-OLTP5
QA2-DW1
QA2-DW2
Dev-OLTP
Dev-OLTP5
Dev-DW1
Dev-DW2
Prod-OLTP
Prod-OLTP5
Prod-DW1
Prod-DW2
```